# javascript not working

Tags: php, javascript

I have following javascript code. Its a timer code. Timer stops if quiz is 3 for 3 seconds and starts after 3 seconds for 20 seconds. But this code is not working for if quiz is anything else than 3. Can anyone help me with this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var days = 0  
  var hours = 0
  var minutes = 0
  var seconds = 20
  var delay_countdown = <?php echo ($quiz == 3) || 0 ; ?>;
function setCount ()
{
  document.getElementById("remain").innerHTML = seconds+" seconds";
  SD=window.setTimeout( "setCount()", 1000 );
  if (delay_countdown) { 
    return
  }
  seconds--;
  if (seconds < 0){
      minutes--;
      seconds = 59
  }
  if (minutes < 0){
      hours--;
      minutes = 59
  }
  if (hours < 0){
      days--;
      hours = 23
  } 

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script works for me if $quiz is anything else than 3(if it's 3 delay_countdown will be true and you return the function on the 4th line).

Supply a different delay-time when delay_countdown is true:

```
SD=window.setTimeout( setCount, (delay_countdown)?3000:1000 );
```

and set `delay_countdown` to `false` before leaving the function:

```
  if (delay_countdown) { 
    delay_countdown=false;
    return;
  }
```